# MDX query for Top down multiple dimensions

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have following Dimensions of same level :

```
    [Area].[Area ID]
    [Discipline].[Discipline ID]
```

and i have following measure:

```
    [Measures].[Risk Score]
```

Note: These dimensions are related to the fact through a Many-to-many relations through another fact table (Project)

I want to retrieve the Top 5 Risks for every discipline in every Area so for example,

If we have Discipline: **Mechanical**; and Area: **A & B**
I want to get:

1) Top 5 Risks of Mechanical Discipline in Area A

2) Top 5 Risks of Mechanical Discipline in Area B

I tried the following code which for some reason is only working for the First Area :

```
    Exists
    (    
       [Risk Dimensions].[RISKSID].[RISKSID],
       GENERATE
       (
          EXCEPT([Area].[Area ID].MEMBERS, [Area].[Area ID].UNKNOWNMEMBER), 
          [Area].[Area ID].CURRENTMEMBER
          *
          GENERATE
          (
              EXCEPT([Discipline].[Discipline ID].MEMBERS, [Discipline].[Discipline  ID].UNKNOWNMEMBER), 
              [Discipline].[Discipline ID].CURRENTMEMBER
              *
              TopCount
              (
                  [Risk Dimensions].[RISKSID].[RISKSID],
                  5,
                  [Measures].[Assessment P-I Score Float]
              )
           )
        )
    )
```

For some reason it is only working for the First Area and the next one will have extra fields

Any help is appreciated